# how to load json file and use fetch function and by this how to create network chart?

Tags: javascript, json, vis.js

I am not able to load the JSON file. By loading the JSON file I will be able to create a network chart. I am using vis.js  http://visjs.org/docs/network/#importGephi library to create the network chart.

This is my javascript file:

```
    var json = loadJSON("data.json");
    function drawNetwork(json) {
    var parseOptions = {
    edges: { inheritColors: false},
    nodes: {fixed: true, parseColor: false}
    }
    var parsed = vis.network.convertGephi(json, parseOptions);
    var data = {
     nodes: parsed.nodes,
     edged: parsed.edges
    };
      // create a network
      var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
      // initialize your network!
      var network = new vis.Network(container, data);
    }
        fetch('data.json')    // here i am using fetch() 
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
         }).then(function(json) {
           drawNetwork(json);
         }).catch(function(err){
         console.log('Fetch error : -S',err);
    });
```

This is my JSON file : data.json

```
{ "nodes": [
    {"id":"a", "label":"a"},
    {"id":"b", "label":"b"},
    {"id":"c", "label":"c"}
    {"id":"d", "label":"d"},
    {"id":"e", "label":"e"},
    {"id":"f", "label":"f"}
    ],
"edges": [
    {"source":"a", "target":"b"},
    {"source":"b", "target":"d"},
    {"source":"a", "target":"c"},
    {"source":"c","target":"d"},
    {"source":"d","target":"e"},
    {"source":"e","target":"a"},
    {"source":"f","target":"c"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to load". What errors are you getting? Please be specific so others can help you.

Comment: data in json file is not able to create network chart.

Comment: Please add the additional information to the question. It will be hard for others to find it in the comments later.

Answer (score 0):

The method `convertGephi` does not exist:

```
var parsed = vis.network.convertGephi(json, parseOptions);
```

You probably mean parseGephi?

```
var parsed = vis.network.parseGephi(json, parseOptions);
```

See also a working example:

http://visjs.org/examples/network/data/importingFromGephi.html